# How to find the last element of array in binary search

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

In binary Search algorithm, the upper-bound element is `array.length-1`, then how can I find the last element of an array?

If the lower-bound and upper-bound for element of an array of length 8 is 6 and  7 respectively, then my mid element coming out as:

mid=(6+7)/2 i.e. 6 in java

Comment: Isn't the last element index is `array.length-1`

Comment: This is pretty poorly worded in my opinion so hopefully my answer answers the correct question.

Comment: @Justin - agreed. I'm assuming Dusk is getting an infinite loop when he searches for a key. If this is happening, it suggests the bisected subranges have a single item overlap, so a deterministic which-subrange test can (repeatedly) choose the wrong one. The last-item-in-the-array is a bit of a red herring - there will be other fail-cases. Looks like you guess the same - but it's a bit of a leap from the wording in the question.

Comment: @Joel- You've completely inappropriately retagged a bunch of questions with [multiway-tree]. Please stop doing this; I'm forced to manually remove the tags each time. Some of your edits were legit, but with a question like this I can't possibly see how you think the tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really comes down to using the right compares with the correctly chosen midpoint. For instance (without variable type declarations),

```
binsearch(a,val,left,right){
    if(left==right) return left;
    mid = (left+right)/2;
    if(a[mid] < val)
        return binsearch(a,val,mid+1,right);
    else
        return binsearch(a,val,left,mid);
}
```

will give you the index of the leftmost element that matches val (even if it is the rightmost element in the array). You don't need to explicitly check the last two or round up rather than using the built in integer truncation.

However, if you want the index of the rightmost element that is equal to val then you need to change the < operator to > and mid should be given by

```
mid = (left+right+1)/2;
```

It's as simple as that.

Edit: One more thing, I looked at my code that I use for this and realized that you have to to also change the the calls to binsearch to end up on the rightmost element. I'll just post the full code for this (which I should have done in the first place). Here's a binary search to find the rightmost element equal to the val.

```
binsearch(a,val,left,right){
    if(left==right) return left;
    mid = (left+right+1)/2;
    if(a[mid] > val)
        return binsearch(a,val,left,mid-1);
    else
        return binsearch(a,val,mid,right);
}
```

Comment: This looks correct, but I don't like that +1. My version means that replacing the "<" with "<=" is sufficient to change from a first >= to a last <= - no need to worry about keeping my +1 or -1 adjustments correct. Upvoted anyway - like I said, it still looks correct.

Comment: You might end up halfway in a streak of the same values and niot on the last one. This works though if you have all unique values in your array.

Comment: If you're talking about finding the rightmost element, that might have been true. I realized I didn't give all of the changes that needed to be made to make it find the rightmost element equal to the val so I just posted a second binsearch code.

Comment: I withdraw the comment about the +1 - as Justin points out, my version is infinite looping - I really should have double checked *before* posting since I don't exactly write binary searches every day !

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use half-open ranges. This way, your upper bound points one step after the last valid item in the array, though your lower bound points directly to the first item. However, during the search, you treat your range as inclusive - the out-of-range upper bound is a valid "no match found" result.

At the start of each iteration you have...

```
lower <= target <= upper
```

"target" means the index that will be found and returned.

You calculate mid as "(upper + lower) / 2". Since this truncates, mid can never be the same as upper, which is important. Since "upper" may be out-of-bounds, we can never legally evaluate "array [upper]".

To find the first item greater-than-or-equal-to the key...

```
if array[mid] >= k :  lower <= target <= mid
if array[mid] <  k :  mid+1 <= target <= upper
```

To find the first item greater-than the key...

```
if array[mid] >  k :  lower <= target <= mid
if array[mid] <= k :  mid+1 <= target <= upper
```

These subranges are inclusive, and must precisely meet but not overlap. A single item overlap at mid (an easy mistake) results in infinite loops, which is part of why we use mid+1 for one subrange.

Note that all that changes between the two searches is the comparison operator.

To find last-less-or-equal, find first-greater and subtract one from the result. You can get -1 if all items in the array are greater than the key.

Note - you only test key against mid in each iteration (you know that the lower and upper bounds are correct already) and you only do one conditional test.

Do the out-of-bounds check and equality check (if that's what you need) *outside* of the loop.

```
int find_first_ge (int key)
{
  int lower = 0;
  int upper = array.length;

  while (upper > lower)
  {
    int mid = (lower + upper) / 2;

    if (array [mid] >= key)  //  for find_first_gt, use ">" here
    {
      upper = mid;
    }
    else
    {
      lower = mid + 1;
    }
  }

  return lower;
}
```

**NOTE**

Edited to correct some mistakes that left this just as infinite-loopy as what it was meant to fix.

The trick is to ensure that the bisected subranges are exactly as needed after each key test, and *always* at least one smaller than the original full range - and through overconfidence and bad memory, that's exactly what I managed to get wrong. The above is based on real working code in a heavily-used library (searches within a node in a multiway-tree library), so if it's wrong I've got *big* problems ;-)

**NOTE**

Edited again to improve wording and simplify the subrange bounds descriptions (noting that although the ranges are half-open, they are treated as inclusive).

Comment: I tested this code out in Python and it looped forever on the last two elements. I even tried it with <= as suggested, but the same problem arose.

Answer (score 0):

You could round up each time.

(6+7)/2.0 == 6.5

Round it up and you'll come up with 7.

Or you could simply add one to your midpoint.

mid = (6+7)/2 + 1

Another way is changing your start or end point to +1 or -1 for the following recursion.  This is what the wikipedia article on the subject shows in some implementations.

min = mid+1

or

max = mid-1

Comment: Downvoters: everyone benefits from an explanation of what's incorrect or not clear.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but fiddling with rounding rules won't give you a valid binary search. If you use anything other than a half-open range, you get fiddly coding issues that make the code slower and more fragile. Different rounding rules can change your failure cases, but doesn't fix the underlying issue. Extra checks within the loop can fix the issue, however you round, but needing this just proves you haven't grokked binary search yet. Half-open ranges, one completion check and one key test per loop, do what binary search just naturally does then add any extra checks *outside* the loop.

Comment: I found this helpful. If you want to understand why you need to round up take an example case of array size 4 [1, 2, 3, 4], where we need to find 4. After the first run through mid = 2 and high = 3. If were to simply take the average we'd get (2+3)/2 = 2. So in order to fix this we need to add 1 (round up) to avoid missing the last value.

Answer (score 0):

When your lower bound and your upper bound are within one of each other, check both.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search is notoriously tricky to get exactly right. There is a very thorough analysis on the various problems and edge cases, along with a correct implementation, in [Programming Pearls](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Pearls-ACM-Press-Bentley/dp/0201657880), a book that every programmer should probably have read at least once.

Comment: Ahem, an *almost* correct implementation! ...  (http://googleresearch.blogspot.hu/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Comment: @LukeUsherwood: ouch - just goes to prove that there's always one more bug!